# Convert Table to Specific Column Wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this. How can I convert to this format?

```
DECLARE @A TaBLE (KeyValue INT, Name VARCHAR(50), Value VARCHAR(512))

INSERT INTO @A 
VALUES (0, 'AccountID', '192507'), (0, 'member_id', '999159'),
       (0, 'firstname', 'Test1'), (0, 'lastname', 'Last1'),
       (1, 'AccountID', '192508'), (1, 'member_id', '999160'),
       (1, 'firstname', 'Test2'), (1, 'lastname', 'Last2')

SELECT * FROM @A
```

I have table rows for this model:

```
KeyValue     Name           Value
-----------------------------------
0          AccountID        192507
0          member_id        999159
0          firstname        Test1
0          lastname         Last1
1          AccountID        192508
1          member_id        999160
1          firstname        Test2
1          lastname         Last2
```

My expected output is:

```
AccountID   member_id   firstname   lastname
--------------------------------------------
192507       999159       Test1      Last1
192508       999160       Test2      Last2
```

I tried this code But it didn't work

```
select *
from
(
  select Name,value
  from @A
) d
pivot
(
  MAX(value)
  for Name in (AccountID,member_id,firstname,lastname)
) piv;
```

Comment: **SHOW US** what you've tried so far - we'll be glad to help - but we won't just write the whole code for you .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dff455cb895144f80e7b04a668410687)

```
SELECT 
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'AccountID' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AccountID,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'member_id' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) member_id ,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'firstname' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) firstname ,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'lastname' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) lastname 
FROM @A
GROUP BY KeyValue
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Code. Its Working Fine. But i want Some Other Methods Like Using Pivot like That.

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60446001/9071943) using Pivot as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result by using `PIVOT`. In your query you just need to select all the columns, like below.

```
SELECT AccountID, member_id, firstname, lastname
FROM
(
  select * from @A
) d
PIVOT
(
  MAX(value)
  FOR Name IN (AccountID, member_id, firstname, lastname)
) piv;
```

You can run the test [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31acf8d26a1e2e3007c2a33a4f8867b5).

Answer (score 1):

In the temp table, you should select all useful information like this

```
select AccountID, member_id, firstname, lastname
from
(
  select * from @A -- instead of `select Name,value`
) d
pivot
(
  MAX(value)
  for Name in (AccountID,member_id,firstname,lastname)
) piv;
```

**[Result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3aced63d36abb092827402f029fffd02)**

[image]

Comment: @Kalirajan Did you check my answer? Please give me your feedback. Thanks.